# Javascript validation for an Adobe Form Field - Email Cc (Multiple email inputs)

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, email, adobe

I'm trying to validate a form field with multiple line inputs in a text field separating them only by a new line.

Here is my code so far:

```js
var splitInput = event.value.split("\n");
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{2,4}$/; 
for(i=0;i<splitInput.length;i++) {
    if (event.value!=""){if (!pattern.test(event.value)){event.rc = false;app.alert("\"" + event.value + "\" is not a valid email address.");};};
}
```

Ps: I'm fairly new to coding but I do understand this is a complicated script.

Comment: Hi there - what's the expected outcome and what are you seeing instead?

Comment: I have answered in a comment below.

Answer (score 0):

@Kurucu

I'd like to be able to input an email into an adobe form with validation of it being an email.

Example:

in one field I'd like to be able to enter each email and separate them with a new line by pressing enter to a multiple-line field:

```
examplename1@email.com
examplename2@email.com
examplename3@email.com
```